# Is ‘return good’ an idiomatic response?

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

Can I reply to someone's ‘Thank you’ with ‘return good’?

For example:

> A: Thank you for all your advice and guidance.
>   B: You're welcome, I hope it will **return good** on you.

Comment: The question in your title is completely different from the text in the body of the question. “It returned to one” is _highly_ unusual, and I would say ungrammatical, whereas “I hope it will return good on you” is grammatical, but unidiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

> A: Thank you for all your advice and guidance.
>   B: **You're welcome.**

Speaker B needn't add anything else, the “You're welcome” implies: *I'm glad my assistance proved to be helpful*,  by adding the OP's phrase **“I hope it will return good on you”** the  standard and idiomatic response changes into something that sounds awkward, and unnatural. I'll try to explain why.

The primary meaning of the verb *[return](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/return)* is *to go back*, e.g., “He often returns to Detroit because his parents still live there”. Although it's true that some people do say “return back”  the adverb *back* is redundant, either say: “She went back to work” or “She returned to work”. In Italian there is the expression *tornare utile*, which translated word for word would be “return useful”, and it seems this is the meaning the OP wants to convey. But in English, we normally say something ***comes in handy*** or ***turns out to be useful***, so if the OP were to say

> B: You're welcome, I hope my advice comes in handy

that would sound more natural and its meaning clearer. There is however an idiom which native speakers use in more formal occasions, it is polite and almost deferential in tone, and it could replace the sentence said by speaker B.

> **to be of service**
>   *to ​help someone*
>
> **A**: Thank you so much for that.
>   **B**: I'm ​glad to have been of service.
>
> <sub>[Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-of-service-to-sb)</sub>

If speaker A were a client or a customer who was thanking B, then B's response “I'm glad to have been of service” would sound appropriate, otherwise the simpler and standard reply “You're welcome” is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

> You're welcome, I hope it will return good on you.

There are people who would use a phrase such as "return good on you" (so you may have heard the phrase spoken), but it's slang or dialect, not "proper" English.

A more "normal" response, conveying essentially the same meaning (as I interpret it from your question), would be something like:

> You're welcome, and I wish you good luck with your project.

(But whether it's "your project" or "your trip" or "your marriage" or whatever depends of course on what the discussion and advice was all about.)

Answer (score -1):

This is good question though, but you should say:

> I hope all of this would be returned to you on a good way.

This specify your intentions and the sentence looks way better like this.

I hope it helps you!!

Comment: Sorry, but no. Your version is ungrammatical (as are several other parts of your answer), which makes it not a very good answer for this site, which is specifically about grammaticality and language usage.